# Serialize to JSON in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, json

how can you serialize an object to JSON in .NET 2.0 using C#?

Comment: Does this question have an answer? Does it need a bounty to get one?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/mref/T_System_Web_Script_Serialization_JavaScriptSerializer.aspx) class from ASP.NET Ajax 1.0, which is compatible with .NET 2.0.

Comment: would rather not install that framework as I'm not using ASP.NET AJAX controls.  We use jQuery

Comment: It's a server-side class.  You don't have to use the client-side code to use that class.

Comment: yea, I know.  You might have sold me here since we don't have .NET 3.5

Comment: where can I get just the assembly?  I think I have to install AJAX 1.0 and then grab it right?

Comment: so are you saying use the AjaxControlToolkit.dll?

Comment: wait, our web project was converted and we're opening it in VS 2008...does that mean we can use .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 10):

Did you try [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) ?

Comment: would like to sort of create a helper method like you can in .NET 3.5 obviously I don't have the library Scott mentions here but would like to roll my own.  I guess that would be easier said than done:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/01/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5.aspx

Comment: at work we are stuck with .net 2.0 and I use json.net, works well.

Answer (score 1):

[JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) has references to a number of serializers in a number of languages, including more than half a dozen in C#.  You should be able to find one which meets your API and licensing needs including [JSONsharp](http://code.google.com/p/jsonsharp/) with the LGPL license and the well-designed [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

If what you're serializing is fairly simple, it's not all that hard to write your own for a specific purpose. The [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) site has the syntax, and it's very straight-forward.

Comment: can't use Json.NET, it requires .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: The JSONsharp should be what you want.  It's LGPL, includes source, has an obtion to take an object and serialize it, and requires only .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to build an RPC server in the .NET side?  If so look at Jayrock (jayrock.berlios.de).  You get the source code and it will compile under 2.0.

Also setting an RPC server is a snap:

```
using Jayrock;
using Jayrock.JsonRpc;
using Jayrock.JsonRpc.Web;
using Jayrock.Json;
using Jayrock.Json.Conversion;


namespace myRPCService
{
    [JsonRpcService("Service")]
    public class Service : JsonRpcHandler
    {

        [JsonRpcMethod("call", Idempotent = true)]
        public string call(string value)
        {
            JsonObject oJSON = JsonConvert.Import(typeof(JsonObject), value) as JsonObject;
           ...
           return oJSON.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just trying to return JSON via a call to our .ashx page

Answer (score 1):

I was able to backport Mono's implementation of System.Json to C# 2.0 with a few minor changes.

You'll need 6 files from [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-4.8.0-branch/mcs/class/System.Json/System.Json) or you can simply download my C# 2.0 project from [here](http://vm1.duckdns.org/Public/System.Json/System.Json.zip).

Note that with System.Json you'll have to manually serialize any non-primitive data type. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026985/how-to-serialize-using-system-json-in-monotouch))

Answer (score -1):

I use below code for JSON message and works well for me.

```
public static class JSONHelper
{
    public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
    }
}
```

Calling JSON serializer in WCF.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string LoadDetails()
{
    LogDetails objSubLog = new LogDetails ();
    List<LogDetails> lstLogdetails;
    DAL objDAL = new DAL();
    lstLogdetails = objDAL.GetLog("ALL", objSubLog);
    return lstLogdetails.ToJSON();
}
```

Comment: This was very useful because I could not use a recent version of Json.NET due to a existing dependency with a legacy version of Sitecore.

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` is not available for .NET 2.0 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer is not available in .net 2.0