# Pass complex json object to ashx via jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json, nested

I have a complex json object on the client (nested arrays) and need to pass this to the server for processing.  I am currently using an ashx, and am experimenting with jquery $.ajax and $.post calls trying to get a usable structure returned to the server.  Could anyone advise me on the best way to pass my complex json object so that I can parse it on the server and access the various nested json arrays etc?  Thanks very much.  I am using ASP.NET 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently do this by passing the JSON object to the server as a string (a single parameter) and then parse it back in to an object.  I prefer the [JSON2 library](http://www.json.org/js.html) to stringify the object into a string.  On server side, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056169/serialize-to-json-in-net-2-0) for ways to deserialize it back into an object.

EDIT: example, this makes a post to handler.ashx with a single parameter 'jsonData'.  I make use of the JSON.stringify method (part of the JSON2 library) -

```
$.ajax({
   url: "handler.ashx",
   type: "POST",
   data: ({jsonData : JSON.stringify(yourDataObject) }),
   success: function(msg){
      alert(msg);
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks - have you an example of a $.ajax or $.post that will pass the entire json object as a single string?  All my attempts seem to pass the object as a huge form array, rather than as a single form value.  Thanks.

Comment: Added an example, do you already have your data object built?  If you set data: JSON.stringify(yourDataObject) then it will break it out into a whole lot of parameters.  You have to explicity set it to a variable (i.e. jsonData).

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the Javascript object as a JSON string and simply pass it as a parameter. On the server side, you'd use a JSON parser to deserialize it into something usable there.

On the client, there's really no such thing as a "JSON Object". It's just Javascript (well ECMAscript if you're persnickety). There are readily-available libraries to do that serialization (see json.org).