# Convert Class Object to Json String in .NET 2.0 without json dll

Tags: c#, json, .net-2.0

I want to pass class object to web service which built in .NEt 4.0 structure but i need to call that in .NET 2.0 framework.
So please let me know how can we convert class object into json based string.

I don't want to use json converter which provided by json.net.

I want to use without that DLL.

Comment: .NET 3.5 has the native functionality for it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I want to use in .NET 2.0

Comment: @harshboss I want to use a feature that doesn't exist in a certain product without using an easily accessible alternative that *does* work.

Comment: It's a pity there's no default functionality, but shit happens, so you have to download this DLL.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056169/serialize-to-json-in-net-2-0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but that is .Net 3.5 on.  I'm not aware of anything made before then that is included within the framework.

If your completely unwilling to use a third party DLL I think your going to have to "Roll your own".