# How can I create JSONARRAY in asp.net or c #

Tags: arrays

I want to create and write `jsonarray` like in this link http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/. I researched but I could not find example that satisfy me.

I know how I write as `JsonString`, for example:

```
string jsonstring = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

But I have a array in asp.net and I want to write that array as JSONarray like this

```
{ "android": 
        [ 
          { "ver": "1.5", "name": "Cupcake", "api": "API level 3" }, 
          { "ver": "1.6", "name": "Donut", "api": "API level 4" }
        ]
}
```

Comment: For what purpose?  If you're returning JSON to the client in response to a request then it's just a string.  You can build and return the JSON directly as a string.  Alternatively, you can use something like the `JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize an object into JSON.  Or, if you're using MVC, you can return a `Json()` result.  Or, with WebAPI, just return the object being serialized.  There are lots of ways to do this.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I know how I write as JsonString ex:  ...string jsonstring = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);... but I have a  array in asp.net and I want to write that array as JSONarray like this { "android": [ { "ver": "1.5", "name": "Cupcake", "api": "API level 3" }, { "ver": "1.6", "name": "Donut", "api": "API level 4" }]}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize to JSON in .NET 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056169/serialize-to-json-in-net-2-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do I have a feeling that the OP isn't a type safe developer and is actually asking, "how do I write a class that serializes to 'this' output?"

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Android {get;set;}

}
public class Bar
{
    public string Ver { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Api { get; set; }
}

var foo = new Foo{
     Android = new List<Bar>
     {
         new Bar { Ver = "1.5", Name = "Cupcake", Api = "Api Level 3"},
         new Bar { Ver = "1.6", Name = "Donut", Api = "Api Level 4"},
     }
};
var bar = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(foo);
```